# Dual boot with both partitions growing inwards

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Is there a way to install ubuntu on a partition with a reverse orientation such that the first sector of the partition would be at the end of the disk?
I know that I would be installing a max of 2 operating systems (dual boot) so I felt that the most optimal solution would be to have two partitions growing inwards.
Something like this: [Partition Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DpEz.png)

I don't have any specific OS or filesystem in mind. I'm open to any linux based OS. Want to know if it's even possible to create a filesystem ( maybe a fork of a current filesystem ) where the static part of the partition (Indices/Superblock/Other metadata) can be on the right side of the partition. Or perhaps a minimal static part but still supports much faster "left" resize grow operations.

Comment: No: You don't get to decide how the ext4 filesystem allocates within the partition. It doesn't "grow" the same way that NTFS grows.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I don’t think any filesystem works like you describe. Assuming you install Windows first you could use Disk Management to shrink it. Then install Ubuntu and use something like GParted to resize it and move it to the right. You could then add another partition in the middle formatted in NTFS or something that both systems can read. Use that middle partition for data. That’s about as close as you can get to your description

Comment: Middle partition wouldn't achieve the same purpose, I want to be able to make a linux partition with a fast "Left resize" operation.